# how to solve a String like (3+2*6) to get the result 15?

Tags: java, string, math

I want to make a calculator in java.

I need to know that is there any way to solve a String Mathematically?

for example:

```
String str = "3+2*6";
```

and somehow I'll get:

```
int result = 15;
```

Comment: `3+2*5*` never equals to `15`, its like `3+(2*5)` in real, even more it's like  `3+(10)`.

Comment: `3+2*6 == 15` and `3+2*5 == 13` It's confusing the way it is written, but it is correct.

Comment: @billyonecan 2+2*5 = 3+10 = 13

Comment: @Azad `3+2*6` (as in the title) is `15`, `3+2*5` (as in the question) is `13`... both are correct.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ScriptEngineManager mg = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mg.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String val = "3+2*5";
System.out.println(engine.eval(val));
```